# How Do I Set Canonical Tags Using HTTP Header Method In JSON for Firebase Site?

Tags: json, firebase, canonical-link

I’m trying to set set self referencing canonical links for every URL on my Firebase hosted site by using the HTTP header method of setting canonical tags rather than manually inserting the link `<rel="canonical" href="https://example.com” />` tag into the the HTTP on every webpage of the site.

For context, I want to apply [this method](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-header-method) (as outlined from google) into my Firebase site.

Does anyone know the JSON code I need to insert to do this in firebase?